# HLSL Matrix Storage

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, hlsl

I recently came along an [article](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/412504-hlsl-and-matrix-multiplication/) that states the following for direct3d and hlsl:

Matrix in memory normally.

```
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
```

Normally a vector * matrix (ex. a D3DXMatrixTransform) will do:

```
outx = vec dot (11,21,31,41)
outy = vec dot (12,22,32,42)
outz = vec dot (13,23,33,43)
outw = vec dot (14,24,34,44)
```

When a matrix is given to a shader, it is transposed and stored in 3/4 constant registers.

```
c0 = 11,21,31,41
c1 = 12,22,32,42
c2 = 13,23,33,43
c3 = 14,24,34,44
```

Next, in the shader performing a `mul(vec,mat)` will do this:

`v0 = input register containing position`
`r0 = temp register`

```
dp4 r0.x, v0, c0 // (r0.x = v0 dot c0)
dp4 r0.y, v0, c1
dp4 r0.z, v0, c2
dp4 r0.w, v0, c3
```

...the same as D3DXMatrixTransform.

The above brings up two questions:

1. `mul(vec,mat)`, according to the [specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will consider a mul() in this order to be a multiplication between a row vector and row-major matrix. Yet the constant registers seem to be storing columns instead of rows. Does this mean mul() has a separate execution method for when the input matrix is stored in constant registers, and when it isn't? (ex. when the matrix is created inside the shader, it isn't stored in constant registers)
2. what happens when `mul(mat, vec)`, assuming the matrix here is also saved in constant registers (passed externally into the shader)?

Comment: You can specify whether your matrices are row- or column major when compiling the Shader. I guess this behaviour is dependent on that options.

Comment: +1 Nice, I didn't know that you could set row- or column major. I agree it's probably dependent, but it doesn't really answer any of the questions I put up.

Comment: Thats why I posted it as a comment ;)